# Issue to create hexagon using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create `hexagon` using image without set background image using css.

I tried below code where display perfect but its issue in email. Background image not set in email so need to `remove from background` and need to set any other way. I tried lots of different way to set but not succeed. As i am not designer so.

I used below code which done but not need to set any other way.

```
<div class="hexagon pic">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>

.hexagon {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/400/400/);
    width: 400px;
    height: 346px;
    position: relative;
}

.hexagon span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    width: 200px;
}

.top {
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 173px solid transparent;
}

.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 173px solid transparent;
}
```

Anyone have a idea.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me like you want `clip-path`. See https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/. Also, check browser support before using.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="hexagon">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

//styles

```
#hexagon {
width: 100px;
height: 55px;
background: red;
position: relative;}


#hexagon:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -25px;
left: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 25px solid red;}

#hexagon:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -25px;
left: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 25px solid red;}

#hexagon > img { height: inherit; width: inherit; }
```

This will do the work.

Comment: Thanks for response but i want to set image into hexagon without use background-image. any idea?

Comment: yep, you can just replace div with img.

Comment: No any effect.. can you do it in jffidle...where i can see. Thanks

Comment: Background-image not send in email so i want to remove it..please read my questions...i already implemented it but remove background image and want to implement other way...Thanks

Comment: ohhh lol, i forgot the initial condition though. well i'll work on it